# Would like to know how to properly use `%>%` in `mapply`?

Tags: r, mapply

Would like to know how to combine `%>%` with `mapply` in a proper way.
here is the toy sample

```
A = data.table(a = letters[1:3], b = 3:1) 
mapply(function(x, y) str_c(x,"---", y), A$a, A$b)
```

it gives a named character vector as following

```
      a       b       c 
"a---3" "b---2" "c---1"
```

However, it generates a new variables which I try hard to avoid, and would like to make it in this form:

```
A %>% mapply(function(x, y) str_c(x,"---", y), .$a, .$b)
```

but the result is

```
  object '.' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Please advise how I can make it?

Comment: Use `A %>% {mapply(function(x, y) str_c(x,"---", y), .$a, .$b)}`. The thing you are piping will always be passed to the first parameter of the function you are calling unless you have a single `.` somewhere. Having `.$a` will not change where the value is passed

Comment: @MrFlick I was told that the dot(.) works as placeholder.

Comment: The dot only works as a place holder when it's alone. When it's used with a function like `$`, it doesn't redirect the pipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain why your code isn’t working, you need to know that writing `obj %>% f(args)` *always* inserts `obj` as the first argument in the call to `f`, unless you use `.` on its own as another argument. In other words, it’s equivalent to

```
obj %>% f(., args)
```

Since you don’t use `.` on its own as an argument (even though you use `.$a` and `.%b`), your call is equivalent to

```
A %>% mapply(., function(x, y) str_c(x,"---", y), .$a, .$b)
```

… which doesn’t work, since `mapply` expects its first argument to be a function.

As Ronak’s answer shows, to circumvent this you can put `f(args)` into `{…}`:

```
obj %>% {f(args)}
```

This syntactic form explicitly disables the rule about inserting `.` as explained above. It’s a special case defined for this purpose.

Alternatively, you could use another pipe operator from ‘magrittr’, the [*exposition pipe*, `%$%`](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/exposition.html). This one works differently: it pulls out named components from the left-hand expression. That way, you could write

```
A %$% mapply(function(x, y) str_c(x,"---", y), a, b)
```

Comment: Hi, Konrad, you have provided much more than I could have expected. I was expecting an advice for the right way of doing things. Yet, I have learned the right way of  regarding the pipeline. `%>%` is more like passing a reference, and the `%$%` is more like passing an entity. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem to right place to use `%>%`. If you need it to for learning purpose use :

```
A %>% {mapply(function(x, y) stringr::str_c(x,"---", y), .$a, .$b)}
```

Comment: many thanks! Would like to ask further that you advised to use it in learning purpose, why so?

Comment: I meant I would not use ` %>%` for such cases because it is more confusing than convenient.

Comment: true. After a while, the meaning of the sentence is becoming blurred.